# How to deduce the relation of two sets from specific integrals on them?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Suppose that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are measurable sets contained in $[0, 1]$. If there exist $0 \leqslant a_1 < a_2 < \cdots$ such that\begin{align*}
> \int_{A_1} x^{a_n} \,\d x = \int_{A_2} x^{a_n} \,\d x, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+
> \end{align*}
> is it necessarily true that $m(A_1 \setminus A_2) = m(A_2 \setminus A_1) = 0$? (Here $m(\,·\,)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.)

**My progress so far:**

If $m(A_1 \setminus A_2) = 0$ or $m(A_2 \setminus A_1) = 0$, the assertion is true since $y = x^{a_1}$ is a continuous function on $(0, 1]$. So next it can be assumed that $m(A_1 \setminus A_2) > 0$ and $m(A_2 \setminus A_1) > 0$.

Now, if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are “seperated,” i.e. there exists $x_0 \in (0, 1)$ such that$$
\begin{cases}
m(A_1 \setminus [x_0, 1]) = 0\\
m(A_2 \setminus [0, x_0]) = 0
\end{cases} \text{ or } \begin{cases}
m(A_1 \setminus [0, x_0]) = 0\\
m(A_2 \setminus [x_0, 1]) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
(assuming the first scenario for simplicity), **and** if $\lim\limits_{n → ∞} a_n = +∞$, then the assertion can be proved as below: Since $m(A_2 \setminus [0, x_0]) = 0$ and $m(A_2 \setminus A_1) > 0$ imply that$$
m(A_2 \setminus (A_1 \cup [0, x_0])) > 0,
$$
then the regularity of Lebesgue measure implies that $A_2 \setminus (A_1 \cup [0, x_0])$ contains an open interval $(x_1, x_2)$. Thus\begin{gather*}
\frac{x_0^{a_n + 1}}{a_n + 1} = \int_0^{x_0} x^{a_n} \,\d x \geqslant \int_{A_1} x^{a_n} \,\d x\\
= \int_{A_2} x^{a_n} \,\d x \geqslant \int_{x_1}^{x_2} x^{a_n} \,\d x = \frac{1}{a_n + 1} (x_2^{a_n + 1} - x_1^{a_n + 1}),
\end{gather*}
which implies that$$
\left( \frac{x_0}{x_1} \right)^{a_n + 1} \geqslant \left( \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right)^{a_n + 1} - 1. \quad \forall n \geqslant 1
$$
But making $n → ∞$ yields a contradiction.

---

**Update 1:** The reasoning above is false as is explained in @zhw's (deteled) answer.

**Update 2:** I would also award the bounty to any answer that proves the assertion **in details** with additional but mild assumptions on $\{a_n\}$.

Comment: I think if $\sum_n \frac{1}{a_n} = +\infty$, then $m(A_1\setminus A_2) = m(A_2\setminus A_1) = 0$, since the linear span of $\{x^{a_n} : n \ge 1\}$ is (uniformly) dense in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: @mathworker21 That sounds like an established theorem. If you'd like to write an answer that shows with some details how to prove the assertion based on your assumption, and present some references to books that state this theorem, I'd be glad to accept it as well.

Comment: @Saad As I wrote in another comment, Muntz-Szasz is in Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis. It's in Chapter 15, gorgeous proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem: Take $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Then the linear span of $\{1\}\cup\{x^n : n \in S\}$ is uniformly dense in $C([0,1])$ if and only if $\sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n} = +\infty$.

This is called the Muntz-Statz theorem (or something like that) and can be found in Lax's functional analysis book.

I don't know how I can provide any more details on how this theorem implies, for your problem, that $A_1=A_2$ up to null sets if $\sum_n \frac{1}{a_n} = +\infty$. The general fact is that if $f_1,f_2$ are measurable and $\int f_1(x)g(x)dx = \int f_2(x)g(x)dx$ for all $g$ in a dense family of $C([0,1])$, then $f_1 = f_2$ a.e.. Here's one such proof of that very well-known fact: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009055/if-int-fg-0-for-all-continuous-function-g-then-f-0-a-e). The proof I would give is to just look at $g$ a continuous approximation of a dirac delta.

Comment: The doubt in my mind is that how this theorem can be applied here since $I_A(x)$ is not even in $C([0,1])$. But thanks for your reference. (+1)

Comment: @Saad it doesn't matter. If $f_1,f_2$ are measurable functions such that $\int f_1(x)g(x)dx = \int f_2(x)g(x)dx$ for all $g$ in a dense family of continuous functions, then $f_1 = f_2$ a.e..

Comment: The Muntz-Szasz theorem states: If $0<\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \cdots,$ then the linear span of $\{1,t^{\lambda_1},t^{\lambda_2},\dots\}$ is dense in $C([0,1])$ iff $\sum \dfrac{1}{\lambda_n}=\infty.$ It's important to include $1$ in the collection. This theorem can also be found in Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: @mathworker21 Now I see how it's proved, but it seems to be a well-known (previously not known to me) theorem and it would be better if you could present a reference to some book instead of a link. (Well, this is not mandatory for the bounty.) Now I'll wait to see if there's any other proof using weaker assumptions, and I'd award the bounty if nothing else comes out.

Comment: @Saad I really don't see how a reference to a book would be better than a link with a direct proof. In any event, I think your question is a very good one, and I'll continue to think about it (in the generality you asked).

Comment: Yes , any radial non increasing $L^1$ function $g$ would do

Answer (score 1):

This is not an aswer but an extended comment: You wrote "the regularity of Lebesgue measure implies that $A_2 \setminus (A_1 \cup [0, x_0])$ contains an open interval $(x_1, x_2)$". That is not true. There are sets of positive measure containing no interval.

But we can fix your proof for the "separated" case: WLOG $A_1\subset [0,a),A_2\subset (a,1]$ and both sets have positive measure. Suppose we have

$$\int_{A_2}x^p \,dx = \int_{A_1}x^p \,dx$$

for an unbounded set of positive $p.$

Now there exists $a<b<1$ such that $[b,1]\cap A_2$ has positive measure. Thus

$$\tag 1 b^p\cdot m([b,1]\cap A_2)\le\int_{A_2}x^p \,dx .$$

As you had,

$$\tag 2\int_{A_1}x^p\,dx\le \frac{a^p}{p+1}.$$

Since $b>a,$ it is easy to see that

$$\frac{a^p}{p+1} < b^p\cdot m([b,1]\cap A_2)$$

for large $p.$ This is a contradiction, so there can be no "separated" sets $A_1,A_2$ of positive measure that have your property.

Comment: This is indeed much more elegant for the seperated case, and makes my use of regularity totally unnecessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=e^{-|y|}  $

$B_1=\{y: e^{-|y|} \in A_1 \}$

$B_2=\{y: e^{-|y|} \in A_2 \}$

$ \int_{[0,1]}1_{A_1}x^{a_n}dx =\int_{[0,\infty]}1_{B_1}e^{-|y|}e^{-a_n|y|}dy$

If $\int_{[0,\infty]}1_{B_1}e^{-|y|}e^{-a_n|y|}dy =\int_{[0,\infty]}1_{B_2}e^{-|y|}e^{-a_n|y|}dy$

$$a_n\int_{[0,\infty]}((1_{B_1}-1_{B_2})e^{-|y|}e^{-a_n|y|}dy=0$$

set $g(y)=(1_{B_1}-1_{B_2})e^{-|y|}$

$a_n\int_{[0,\infty]}g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=a_n\int_{[-\infty,0]}g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=0$

so $$\lim_{a_n \to \infty}2a_n\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=0$$

If we let the measure $v_n(S)=\int_Se^{-n|y|}dy$ on a measurable set $S$

Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}g(y)dv_n}{v_n([-\epsilon,\epsilon])}=0$$

This implies the sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ cannot be seperated and also implies sets $A$ and $B$ cant be seperated

Comment: I haven't read through this answer, but $I_A$ in the first integral should be changed into something else after the subtition $x=\exp(-|y-z|)$.

Comment: @Saad you are right, I have to edit

Comment: @Saad I think I made the corrections

Comment: Basically I can see your idea is to use the double-exponential kernel to get the almost everywhere identity, but the problem is that $g$ is actually a function depending on both $y$ and $z$, so the convergence result at the end doesn't hold.

Comment: @Saad yes I was wrong, it only shows the sets can't be seperated