# How continuous are functions that map dense sets to dense sets?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a function with the property that for every dense $D \subset [0,1]$, $f(D)$ is dense in $f([0,1])$. We can note that $f$ need not be continuous. For instance, consider $f(x)=\left|\sin \ \left(\frac{1}{x-1/2}\right)\right|$ with $f(1/2)=0$.

> Is there a nowhere continuous example? If not, how large must the continuity set of such functions be?

Comment: As a user with 10k+ rep, why did you post a problem-statement question?

Comment: @Saad You're not expected to provide an essay for every question. Here, I provided a non-continuous example, which is sufficient context.

Comment: @Saad I've seen you make this comment several times in recent days on essentially reasonable posts. Consider practicing what you preach (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581544/how-to-deduce-the-relation-of-two-sets-from-specific-integrals-on-them) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578797/how-to-compute-the-determinant-of-this-toeplitz-matrix), which have as much if not less context than my question above does).

Comment: Take $f(x)$ to be sampled from uniform random iid variables.

Comment: On second thought, my idea above doesn't work.  With probability $1$ you can construct a sequence that maps into $[0,1/2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nowhere continuous example.

Let $U_1,U_2,U_3,\dots$ enumerate all rational intervals contained in $[0,1]$.

For each $n$ choose two distinct points $u_n,v_n\in U_n$.

Let $I_n=\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

Define $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ as follows:

$$f(x)=u_n\text{ if }x\in I_n\cap\mathbb Q;$$
$$f(x)=v_n\text{ if }x\in I_n\setminus\mathbb Q;$$
$$f(0)=0.$$

Plainly $f$ is nowhere continuous. If $D$ is a dense subset of $[0,1]$, then for each $n$ we have $D\cap I_n\ne\emptyset$, so $f(D)\cap U_n\ne\emptyset$.